# SQL query to update a field by -1 if its not NULL or 0

Tags: sql

I need to update a value in all records in a table by -1.
Some values are 0 and NULL, these are to be left as they are.
Whats the best way to do this ?

Steve

Comment: Do you want to update all records to - 1 irrespective of 0 and null ?

Answer (score 2):

You just use `update` with a `where` clause:

```
update t
    set col = -1
    where col is not null and col <> 0;
```

If you mean "decrement" rather than set to -1, then use `set col = col - 1`.

Comment: I think the values of `col` would be unsigned, so a `WHERE col > 0` would be more logical...

Comment: @GordonLinoff The `where` clause makes no sense. If `col <> 0`, it cannot be null because `null` cannot be equal or not equal to something. So, `col <> 0` automatically means that `col is not null`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `where` clause with `<> 0` condition

```
update Yourtable
    set col = -1
    where col <> 0;
```

`Where col <> 0` will filter out the `NULL` values so we don't need that condition it is just redundant.

Comment: You have correctly pointed that `Where col <> 0` will filter out the `NULL` values. Others missed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these conditions in the where clause:

- Column is not NULL
- Column is not zero

Something like:

```
Update <table-name> SET column = -1 where column!=0 and column is not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
update `table_name`
    set `field_name` = `field_name`-1
    where `field_name` is not null and `field_name` != 0;
```